# Removing a model in rails (reverse of "rails g model Title...")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, migration

```
rails g model Rating user_id:integer message:string value:integer
```

How can I completely remove this model? Thanks

Comment: Mikhail's top answer below applies to a model created in the last migration. Those who want to remove a model and its table that have been around for a while, [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15648268/what-is-the-best-way-to-drop-a-table-remove-a-model-in-rails-3) describes exactly what to do.

Answer (score 214):

When you generate a model, it creates a database migration. If you run 'destroy' on that model, it will delete the migration file, but not the database table. So before run

```
bundle exec rails db:rollback
rails destroy model <model_name>
```

For rails versions before 5.0 and higher use `rake` instead of `rails`

```
bundle exec rake db:rollback   
rails destroy model <model_name>
```

Comment: :( Read the first line and did it. It was my fault, but a correctly-ordered answer may have helped.

Comment: if it's development and you don't afraid to lose your data you can run `bundle exec rake db:drop db:create db:migrate`. It will be a new empty database.

Comment: Ye thanks. I restored the migration from the Trash but it turns out I had another missing migration too so I'm going to do what you suggest

Comment: @MikeT You what? Restored the migration from the trash? You don't use any VCS? o_O You absolutely should!

Comment: Worked for me, but I also had to go into routes.rb and delete " devise_for :MODEL"

Answer (score 65):

Try this

```
rails destroy model Rating
```

It will remove model, migration, tests and fixtures

Comment: It removes all, but it do not create downgrade migration or something.

Answer (score 33):

For future questioners:  If you can't drop the tables from the console, try to create a migration that drops the tables for you.  You should create a migration and then in the file note tables you want dropped like this:

```
class DropTables < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    drop_table :table_you_dont_want
  end

  def down
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
end
```

Comment: Great answer, will behave as expected with a capistrano deploy.

Answer (score 24):

1. To remove migration (if you already migrated the migration)

   ```
   rake db:migrate:down VERSION="20130417185845" #Your migration version
   ```
2. To remove Model

   ```
   rails d model name  #name => Your model name
   ```

Comment: `rails d model` is what I'm looking for to reverse my `rails g model`.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a different implementation of Jenny Lang's answer that works for Rails 5.

First create the migration file:

```
bundle exec be rails g migration DropEpisodes
```

Then populate the migration file as follows:

```
class DropEpisodes < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    drop_table :episodes
  end
end
```

Running `rails db:migrate` will drop the table.  If you run `rails db:rollback`, Rails will throw a `ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration` error.

Comment: This is a useful answer - but the command doesn't work for me. I used:

bundle exec rails generate migration DropEpisodes

And then I would also use model deletion code below as well.