# Deleting empty asset files in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

When using scaffolding in Rails, you end up with placeholder .css/.scss and .js/.coffee files under the **assets** directories. Unless I am adding something to one they will stay empty.

I would assume the assets pipeline would ignore the empty files when compiling, but is there any reason I wouldn't just delete them all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rails generate scaffold` is just a helper. It simply generated **everything** that could possibly be useful to you.

Sure you can delete all unneeded files. You could also delete a model or controller after it has been created if you don't need it anymore.

Comment: I assume it would be best to generate a migration to drop any tables, something like: rails destroy model my_models ?

Comment: You have to distinguish: **1.** If you've used the rails generator to generate a model (and a migration) - this gets also done by using scaffold - then you also have to create a new migration which drops the tables. So you'd have migration1 which creates the table and migration2 which drops it afterwards. **2.** If you've created your database table without migration (for example using phpMyAdmin or plain SQL in you console), then you should should drop the table by hand, without using migrations. **Also have a look here:** http://stackoverflow.com/a/7106032/1321564